# Navigation with Flow Router, Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am having problem redirecting my clients to some address.

For example, the client go to this url, "http://localhost:3000/home".
If the client go to "http://localhost:3000/msg" using this code,

```
<a href="msg" >Link</a>
```

It is working. But when the client from "http://localhost:3000/people/231233213123" and the client click the link with this code,

```
<a href="msg">Link</a>
```

It will go to "http://localhost:3000/people/231233213123/msg".

I need to make the client go to "http://localhost:3000/msg".

I tried usin this code,

```
<a href="../../msg">Link</a>
```

But it will redirect to "http://localhost:3000/people/msg".

I am using Flow router in React and Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a slash before the url:

```
<a href="/msg">Link</a>
```